# Rewrite script from js to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that I want to make more bulletproof. At the moment the page breaks because class box-tip is not found. To make this bulletproof and not throw an error how can I rewrote the below code to jquery getting the same results as js

```
function applyRecommendedSleeveLength(selectedVal) {
  if (selectedVal !== undefined) {
var recommendedVal = map[selectedVal.trim()];
var selected = $('.attribute__swatch--selected:first          div').text().trim();
if (recommendedVal === null || recommendedVal === undefined) {
  selectedVal = $('.attribute__swatch--selected:first   div').text().trim();
  recommendedVal = map[selectedVal.trim()];
}

if (selected === null || selected === '' || selected === undefined) return;

var recommendedLis =              document.querySelectorAll('[class*="attribute__swatch--length-' + recommendedVal + '"] div');
recommendedLis.forEach(function(recommendedLi, i) {
  if (recommendedLi !== null && recommendedLi !== undefined) {
    recommendedLi.classList.add('showBorder');
    $('.box-tip').show();
    var currentPosition = $('.showBorder').parent().position().left;
    var sleeveRecom =    document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip');
      var info = sleeveRecom.length ? sleeveRecom[0] : false;
      info.style.paddingLeft = currentPosition + -75 + 'px';
  }
});
```

}
}

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: For future reference, and so you don't annoy your colleagues, please learn better tab discipline.

Comment: Why not just use jQuery to get the `.box-tip` elements, as you already do a couple of lines above? That way it won't matter if there's any matching elements in the DOM or not, as jQuery is tolerant of that

Comment: Could add a check to see if box tip exists: `if ($('.box-tip').length) {}` but as Rory says, jquery is usually pretty tolerant so I don't see what would be breaking in your above code.  Also why do you get your box tip with jQuery and then with native js, I think it is the native js that is breaking as you set info to false, it won't have a style property

Comment: Can you display how I can feature jquery solution into my code

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the div exists, you can use this (using JQuery):

```
if ( $('.box-tip').length != 0 ){
  //do something
}
```

OR- since you've edited your post- without JQuery:

```
if ( document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip').length != 0 ){
      //do something
}
```

Comment: Do i wrap the whole function from top around this statement? Where do I put it?

Comment: Where you're trying to access box-tip and want to make sure it's there.  i.e. - before using '$('.box-tip').show()'. (which should be inside the 'do something' part.

Comment: I think using jquery will be the better option for this as you say it won't force errors. Any idea how I can transfer the above code into jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery for all of this. If the class doesn't exist the jQuery methods won't cause errors

```
function applyRecommendedSleeveLength() {
    $('.box-tip').show().first().css('paddingLeft',  (currentPosition - 75) + 'px');       
}
```

Comment: how do i feature 'showborder' into this? please see code in my question